# Undesirable array returning to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting learn Ruby on Rails, and started with a basic CRUD. A problem I'm having is in the index view: everything that I saved is showed, but also an array with everithing saved is returned.

The index method in my controller:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

My view:

```
<%= @categories.each do |c| %> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= c.name %> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New category', "/categories/new" %>
```

What is showed in the browser:

```
Healt
Supermarket
[#<Category id: 13, name: "Healt", created_at: "2016-02-17 13:30:22", updated_at: "2016-02-17 13:30:22">, #<Category id: 14, name: "Supermarket", created_at: "2016-02-17 13:30:42", updated_at: "2016-02-17 13:30:42">]New category
```

Why that happens? How can I avoid that?

Comment: @Pavan, it's the same question. I searched for the answer here before, but I really didn't found. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line has the `=` for output so it will (at the end) output the iteration (the array you did `each` on)

```
<%= @categories.each do |c| %>
```

If you don't want that just remove the equals

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I didn't know the difference between `<%=` and `<%`.